# Hashtable elements are unordered, I want to retreive elements in same order as we are inserted

Tags: java, hashtable

The Hashtable elements are unordered, Is it possible to retreive elements in same order as we are inserted.
I know that LinkedHashMap lists the elements in the order they were inserted.
and the TreeHashMap iterates the elements in their natural order which they have inserted.

Comment: You can't with `Hashtable`. You seem to know the alternatives.

Comment: Wait? What is your question?

Comment: Here I dont want to use Hashmap or linkedhasmap. is it possible to iterate the Hashtable elements in the order of their insertion is my question.

Comment: You are out of options then.

Comment: Why not LinkedHashMap?

Comment: I guess I have a different question: why do you need hash-based structure? It seems like you want to traverse the elements, so a hash is not the right data-structure.

Comment: I would like four large round objects, surrounded by rubber-encased cushions of air.  I wish to attach these objects to the axles of my car, to enable it to move smoothly along roads.  Can you re-invent something for me please?

Comment: Because hashtable is synchornized..I dont want mess my code with synchronized block..Just i am asking is it possible or not, otherwise i will use linkedhashmap

Comment: Use `Collections.synchronizedMap(..)` and wrap your `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `LinkedHashMap`.

LinkedHashMap is a Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.

Comment: This answer, as written, is not useful. The OP already knows about `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: True, @Sotirios, but I wonder what kind of answer the OP would consider useful.  It seems they answered their own question in the second sentence.